# chave estrangeira método cadastro

Tags: java, javafx, método

Estou com problemas em relação a chave estrageira. Tenho um cadastro de empresa e nesse cadastro coloquei 3 chaves estrageiras, que é aquele tal relacionamento 1:n, né?

Enfim, eu só consigo colocar as colunas na própria tabela, mas quando é a chave estrageira eu não consigo.

```java
//Metodo de cadastro 

public void cadastroempresa(CadastroEmpresa Cadastro){
SQL....
prepared...

pst.setString(1, Cadastro.getNomeEmpresa());
    pst.setString(2, Cadastro.getCnpjEmpresa());
    pst.setString(3, Cadastro.getNomeResponsavel());
    // A linha abaixo é a fk de outra tabela que tá dando erro.
    // Essa fk tá dentro de um combobox já preenchido com os dados 
    pst.setInt(4,Cadastro.getfkestado());
}
```

Comment: mas qual é o erro?

Comment: Você concorda que "está dando erro" oferece pouca chance de alguém tentar te ajudar? Qual erro? Qual mensagem de erro aparece pra você?

Comment: Ja consegui resolver, não estava conseguindo por a chave estrangeira no método agora já consegui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - O primeiro passo a verificar, é se o valor que você está pegando da combobox está correto. Você pode fazer essa verificação atribuindo valor para uma variável e através de deburação você enxergar qual o valor da variável. Uma opção mais simples e rápida para verificar, seria utilizar o System.out.println(): `System.out.println(Cadastro.getfkestado());`.

2 - Se após verificar o valor que está obtendo da combobox realmente esteja correto, verique se o valor que você está passando como chave estrangeira realmente existe na outra tabela. Por exemplo, se você fez relacionamento entre uma tabela de empresas e uma tabela de estado. Na tabela de empresa será inserido o valor da chave da tabela de estado. Se for cadastrar uma empresa de Minas Gerais por exemplo,  e o estado Minas Gerais possui a chave com o valor 4 na tabela de estados, você deverá inserir o valor 4 na tabela de empresa. Logo, verifique se o valor que você está passando para a tabela de empresa existe na tabela de estados.

Aguardo sua resposta!